# Keep ID list after insert rows

Tags: sql

I have table A like below

```
Table A:
 ID   Value
 1      A
 2      B
```

**Note** ID is auto Identity

Now I want to duplicate table A and keep new ID of new record inserted

My expectation after insert I have 2 table like below

```
Table A
 ID   Value
 1      A
 2      B
 3      A
 4      B
```

AND

```
Table IDList

Old_ID  New_ID 
 1       3
 2       4
```

NOTE Table IDList is temperary table to keep old and new ID

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps simply:

```
SELECT Old_ID=MIN(ID),  New_ID=MAX(ID)
FROM dbo.TableA
GROUP BY Value
```

<kbd>[**demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/baddb/2/0)</kbd>

Comment: Sorry that is not my expectation. I mean the 2 last record was cloned from 2 first row. So I want create new table to log which Id was cloned from which one.